# Get rows with specific duplicate values SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have a table with no primary key which looks like :

```
NotId  Status
   1   active
   1   inactive
   2   active
   3   inactive
   4   inactive
   5   active
   5   inactive
   5   extended
   6   inactive
   6   extended
```

I want to get all the *NotId*s from the table. And in case duplicate *NotIds* are found, only with *Status* **active** should be returned. Duplicate *NotIds* with other statuses should be skipped. If *NotIds* with status **Active** is not present, then all duplicates should be returned. Note that *Status* is not restricted to *Active and Inactive only*

The expected result :

```
1   active
2   active
3   inactive
4   inactive
5   active
6   inactive
6   extended
```

Comment: Specify the expected result as well, having that table data!

Comment: Should the result contain both of the `('5','active')` rows, or only one of the duplicates? Providing expected result can help illustrate the specification. (The query required to return a specified resultset depends on the specification.)  (Question has been modified.... what if there is another row, `('5','active')` ... and another `('5','active')`

Comment: "Note that Status is not restricted to Active and Inactive only". What if no active row for an NotId, but two other rows? If those other rows have same Status, should both be returned? If those other rows have different Status, should both be returned?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: You have to explain the duplicate part. For example if 3 have another `inactive` will appear on the result?

Comment: but you say `Duplicate NotIds with other statuses should be skipped`, why expected results have `extended` then ?

Answer (score 1):

Use grouping with `min` as

```
select NotId, min(Status) as Status
  from tab
 where Status in ('active','inactive') 
 group by NotId
```

`Status in ('active','inactive')`  depends on the comment

*"Duplicate NotIds with other statuses should be skipped"*

Comment: "Note that Status is not restricted to Active and Inactive only"

Comment: You must change to `where Status in ('active','inactive') `

Comment: @forpas Why? He added "Duplicate NotIds with other statuses should be skipped" ...

Comment: `NotId` is the integer id

Answer (score 0):

Return one row for each NotId. Use `coalesce` combined with `case` expressions to return 'active' if existing, otherwise some other value.

```
select NotId,
       coalesce(min(case when Status = 'active' then Status end), min(Status)) as Status
from tab
group by NotId
```

Answer (score 0):

jarlh solution work great, but if you want to remove the rows where group is greater than 1 and doesnt have active you need to do some work first

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37284a/6)**

```
SELECT `NotId`, CASE WHEN total = 1 
                     THEN result
                     WHEN active > 0 
                     THEN 'active'
                END as `Status`

FROM ( SELECT `NotId`, 
               MAX(`Status`) as result, 
               COUNT(*) as total,  
               COUNT( CASE WHEN `Status` = 'active' THEN 1 END) as active
       FROM Table1
       GROUP BY  `NotId`
  ) as T
WHERE total = 1 or active = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This query satisfies a specification. (The specification may differ from the specification needed for the use case given in the question.)

```
SELECT t.notid
     , t.status
  FROM mytable t 
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT b.notid
              , b.status
           FROM mytable b
          WHERE b.status = 'active'
          GROUP
             BY b.notid
       ) n
   ON n.notid = t.notid
WHERE ( n.notid IS NULL OR t.status = 'active' )
ORDER
   BY t.notid
    , t.status
```

Given:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (notid, status) VALUES
 ('1','active')
,('1','inactive')
,('2','active')
,('3','inactive')
,('4','fee')
,('4','fi')
,('4','fo')
,('4','fum')
,('5','active')
,('5','active')
,('5','inactive')
;
```

The query returns:

```
notid  status
-----  ------
1      active
2      active
3      inactive
4      fee
4      fi
4      fo
4      fum
5      active
5      active
```

This query assumes that `notid` is non-NULL. This will return all rows in the table, including duplicates, excluding rows with status other than 'active' when a row with 'active' status exists for a given `notid`.

Answer (score 0):

I use `group_concat()` to separate the ids that contain `'active'` or not:

```
select tab.* 
from tab inner join (
  select NotId, concat(',', group_concat(Status), ',') like '%,active,%' active
  from tab
  group by NotId
) t
on t.NotId = tab.NotId
where
  t.active = 0
  or
  (t.active = 1 and tab.Status = 'active')
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cuG2iLpF8hRCYbFU18sB4o/0)
**Results**

```
| NotId | Status   |
| ----- | -------- |
| 1     | active   |
| 2     | active   |
| 3     | inactive |
| 4     | inactive |
| 5     | active   |
| 6     | inactive |
| 6     | extended |
```